# Finding integers $a$ such that $a^{2}+1\equiv 2a$ (mod 11)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am having hard time finding the first four integers that satisify this modular equation:
$$
a^{2}+1\equiv 2a\;\text{mod $11$}
$$
All this lies down to finding $a$ that would make $a^{2}-2a+1\equiv0$ mod $11$ and so far I can only think of $a=1$. I would hope for some help.

Comment: Remember that $a\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ means that $a-1=11k$, with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $$\implies11|(a-1)^2\iff11|(a-1)$$ as $11$ is prime

Comment: Ohh I see thank you very much

Comment: You are trying to find the roots of the polynomial $f(X)=X^{2}-2X+1=(X-1)^{2}$ in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}\right)[X]$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$a^2-2a+1=(a-1)^2$$

So you want

$$(a-1)^2\equiv 0\pmod{11}$$

This implies $11|(a-1)^2$. What does this tell you about $a-1$?

Comment: this means that $(a-1)^2=11$ or $1$

Comment: Remember, $11|(a-1)^2$ means $11$ divides $(a-1)^2$, not that $(a-1)^2$ divides $11$.

Answer (score 0):

- HINT

If, $p$ is prime and $n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$,  then

$$\begin{align}n^2 &\equiv 0 ~(\text{mod}~ p)\iff n \equiv 0 ~(\text{mod}~ p) &\end{align}$$